# ViewState variable breaks if the worker process recycles

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have the following property to save certain page level information in the ViewState:

```
protected ViewStateModel Model
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pageModel == null)
            {
                _pageModel = (ViewStateModel) ViewState[_pageModelKey];
                if (_pageModel == null)
                {
                    _pageModel = new ViewStateModel();
                    ViewState[_pageModelKey] = _pageModel;
                }
            }

            return _pageModel;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState[_pageModelKey] = _pageModel = value;
        }
    }
```

This works great and until the IIS worker process is recycles. I get a

> Unable to cast object of type 'ViewStateModel' to type 'ViewStateModel

Now if I debug, I see that the ViewState still contains the object of type ViewStateModel with all its values but if when I compare its type to my defined Model class, it returns false

```
// this always returns false if the worker process has been recycled
  ViewState[_pageModelKey] is ViewStateModel
```

Answer (score 2):

IIS worker process recycling shouldn't affect the ViewState. A recycle can affect `Session` and `Application` state, but the `ViewState` is just an encrypted hidden field on the page. If it were to affect ViewState you'd most likely get the following exception:

> ViewState is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Check out this support [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829743) and see if any of the suggestions help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not ViewState. The problem was that without understanding the consequences properly, I defined the ViewStateModel class within the same aspx page that it was being used in. Since the aspx folders are compiled into dlls with random names, the serialized class in the ViewState can become invalid if the folder is recompiled or even across servers in a web farm. As per [Binary Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> the public and private fields of the object and the name of the class, including the assembly containing the class, are converted to a stream of bytes

So since the name of the dll is not the same, deserialization fails. The right practice is to have all your models defined in a separate class file in either App_Code or a completely different class project